# Merging cells in Matlab (like in Excel) for an array-based table

Tags: excel, matlab, cell-array, array-merge

I wonder how to merge cells in `Matlab` like in `Excel` using `Format cells -> Alignment -> Merge cells`.

Here is an illustration, based on a little piece of code:

```
veg=cell(2,3);
veg{1,1}='apple';
veg{2,1}='green';
veg{2,2}='red';
veg{2,3}='gold';
```

thus is there a way to perform something like

```
 veg{1;1:3} ='apple';
 veg{1;1:3} ='apple';
 Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

Best,

Comment: Not sure what your intent is. I don't believe you can do exactly what you want, that is "merge cells" into one value, but you can make all three of those cells all equal the same value. Then all you need is this: veg(1,1:3) = {'apple'}. Your error comes from using the semicolon instead of a comma, by the way.

Comment: Another option, if you want Excel like functionality, is to not use cells, but to use a uitable variable type. You would have to read up on them and learn how to use them. It's more than can be given in a single answer here.

Comment: thanks. I have been aware of `veg(1,1:3) = {'apple'}`, but my concern:  i use the `report generator` to generate an `RTF doc` and the table used as benchmark as opposed to my `array-based table` was done in Word / Excel,  containing lots of `cell mergers`. What i was doing as a way around based on the suggested command requires me to open the report once converted then merge cells in Word. It does work, acknowledging it's not `100%` efficient as approach.

Comment: are you trying to do something like `rowspan` and `colspan` in HTML? Just remember that a 2D cell array is like a regular "matrix" in shape, only difference is that it holds different data types. It is always tabular in shape..

Comment: @Amro: thx for the info, however it was not my intention to deal with `html` `rowspan/colspan`.

Comment: @dark.vador There is no analog to merge cells in Excel for MATLAB cell arrays.

Comment: @Suever: Thanks for your confirmation.